# Merging two SELECT queries

Tags: mysql, merge

First query:

```
$fpost = $sql->query(" SELECT `p`.`name`, `f`.`id`, `f`.`topic`, `f`.`date`, `f`.`last` 
FROM `posters`, `forum` 
WHERE `f`.`deleted` = 0 
AND `f`.`neg` = ".(int) $neg['id']." 
AND `p`.`id` = `f`.`author` 
ORDER BY `f`.`last` DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch();
```

Second query:

```
$lpost = $sql->query("SELECT `p`.`name`, `f`.`id`, `f`.`topic`, `f`.`date`, `a`.`access` 
FROM `forum`, `posters` 
LEFT JOIN `account` `a` ON (`a`.`id` = `p`.`aid`) 
WHERE `f`.`neg` = ".(int) $neg['id']." 
AND `p`.`id` = `f`.`author` 
AND `f`.`date` = " . (int) $fpost['last'] . " 
LIMIT 1")->fetch();
```

As you can see I'm selecting almost the same fields in both queries. The problem are the conditions.

Is the a possibility to make it in one query?

Comment: do the result sets contain overlaps in the records?

Comment: So tell us, what are you trying to achieve with the first and the second query. In the first query, I assume you look for the latest forum and it's creator. In the second, you look for something by date...

Comment: First query is for the `first post` of the forum. Second query is for the `last post` of the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$neg_id = mysql_real_escape_string($neg['id']);

$query =" (SELECT p.name, f.id, f.topic, f.date, f.last, null as access 
  FROM forum f
  INNER JOIN posters p ON (p.id = f.author)   <<-- use explicit join syntax
  WHERE f.deleted = 0 
  AND f.neg = '$neg_id' 
  ORDER BY f.date ASC                <<-- first post
  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0)
UNION
  (SELECT p.name, f.id, f.topic, f.date, f.last, a.access 
  FROM forum f
  INNER JOIN posters p ON (p.id = f.author)
  LEFT JOIN account a ON (a.id = p.aid) 
  WHERE f.deleted = 0
  AND f.neg = '$neg_id'  
  ORDER BY f.date DESC               <<-- last post
  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) ";
```

**Comments on your code**

**Escaping**
I would advice to use one escaping function and one only.
It simplifies your code and negates to need to worry whether a column is an int or a string.
If you just use `mysql_real_escape_string()` *(or `mysqli_real....()` whichever applies)* and remember to always quote your $vars, then you can use the same escaping everywhere.
It makes your code much cleaner.

**Readability issues**
I have no idea what's up with all the backticks.
To me it looks like you vomited all your the query.
You only need backticks if the identifier is a reserved word _(or contains spaces and such).

**Syntax error**
Not only that, but you use aliases that are not defined, which is a syntax error.

**Implicit joins are an anti-pattern**
You use implicit SQL joins, which is bad form, error prone and confusing.
Use explicit joins instead, it will help you to avoid accidental cross joins and clears up your where clause improving readability.

**If it quacks like a duck....**
If a query does *(almost)* the same thing, it's best to make it **look** the same.
You say that query A selects the first post in a forum and query B selects the last.
These results are very simular, yet the query layout is very different.
That smacks like a code smell and should be avoided.

Comment: I was reading that using `UNION` is not the best idea. What do you think? Also, I'm using PDO, so maybe it does provide any better ideas?

Comment: @Cyclone: A `UNION` is bad sometimes but definitely not in this case, it's only unioning two queries that return 1 row each.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this (and any time I need to build similar queries with multiple optional arguments), I typically build a string first (**note**: I modified the order of the query a bit in an attempt to use less `if` statements):

```
$specialQuery = isset($fpost) && isset($fpost['last']);
$query = "SELECT `p`.`name`, `f`.`id`, `f`.`topic`, `f`.`date`, ";

if($specialQuery) {
  $query .= "`a`.`access` ";
} else {
  $query .= "`f`.`last` ";
}

$query .= "FROM `posters`, `forum` ";

if($specialQuery) {
  $query .= "LEFT JOIN `account` `a` ON (`a`.`id` = `p`.`aid`) ";
}

$query .= "WHERE `f`.`neg` = ".(int) $neg['id']." ". 
          "AND `p`.`id` = `f`.`author` ";

if($specialQuery) {
  $query .= "AND `f`.`date` = " . (int) $fpost['last'] . " ".
            "LIMIT 1";
} else {
  $query .= "AND `f`.`deleted` = 0 ".
            "ORDER BY `f`.`last` DESC LIMIT 1";
}

$result = $sql->query($query)->fetch();
```

I know this looks a bit rough (and for your specific queries, it may be better to stick with the two separate ones). Usually this works better when the queries return the same columns and are simply multiple `AND` or `OR` statements. Hope this helps

Comment: You have just made a simple query next to unreadable. I fail to see the purpose of this obfuscation contest.